# How to get data from mysql for given date range group by weekly,monthly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has data in this format:

```
id name cnt1 created_on
'1','uac','116','2014-09-06 17:16:29'
'2','uac','116','2014-09-06 17:17:06'
'3','uac','90','2014-09-06 21:53:34'
'4','uac','100','2014-08-06 21:53:34'
'5','uac','1','2014-07-06 21:53:34'
'6','uac','2','2014-07-26 21:53:34'
'7','uac','3','2014-09-01 21:53:34'
'8','uac','4','2014-09-02 21:53:34'
'9','uac','5','2014-09-03 21:53:34'
'10','uac','6','2014-09-04 21:53:34'
'11','uac','7','2014-09-05 21:53:34'
'12','uac','8','2014-09-07 21:53:34'
'13','uac','9','2014-09-08 21:53:34'
```

I want data for given date range should be grouped on 1. Weekly 2. Monthly
Also I want that for a week or month I should get data for last dat of week or month. Eg
if I am getting data for monthly I should get following output:

```
'6','uac','1','2014-07-26 21:53:34'
'4','uac','100','2014-08-06 21:53:34'
'13','uac','116','2014-09-08 21:53:34'
```

I tried this query

```
SELECT id,name,cnt1,created_on
FROM qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail
GROUP BY year(created_on), month(created_on);
```

but this is giving me following output

```
'5','uac','1','2014-07-06 21:53:34'
'4','uac','100','2014-08-06 21:53:34'
'1','uac','116','2014-09-06 17:16:29'
```

Please help

Comment: When you use `GROUP BY` you should specify, if you want to e.g. `SUM` values in `cnt1` column.  Why there is 116 for 9/2014 in column cnt1? Is it maximum of all values? Also I miss `cnt2` column values in your list.

Comment: How come your sample data has two columns called CNT1 and CNT2 but only one amount value exists, and then in your query you refer to a column called "TOTAL_TC" which does not appear to exist in your sample?

Comment: Should the third value on the first row of your expected output actually be 2, not 1?

Comment: Realised, have edited my question. @VDohnal 116 is single value its not maximum. I actually dont need sum or avg. I just want latest data for a week/month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually want a `group by` query.  You want to get the last row for each set.  Here is a method using `not exists`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail cd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail cd2
                  WHERE year(cd2.created_on) = year(cd.created_on) and
                        month(cd2.created_on) = month(cd.created_on) and
                        cd2.created_on > cd.created_on
                 ) ;
```

This is saying, in essence:  "Get me all rows from the table where there is no other row with the same year and month and a more recent `created_on` date."  That is a fancy way of saying "Get me the last row for each month."

EDIT;

If you want the values from the first and last date of the month, then use a `join` method instead:

```
select cd.*, cdsum.minco as first_created_on
from qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail cd join
     (select year(cd2.created_on) as yr, month(cd2.created_on) as mon,
             min(cd2.created_on) as minco, max(cd2.created_on) as maxco
      from qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail cd2
      group by year(cd2.created_on), month(cd2.created_on)
     ) cdsum
     on cd.created_on = cd2.maxco;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. works perfectly and I agree with the title re-factor. Was running out of words :-)

Comment: One more question, What if I want to display date as first day of that month/week. Right now value is correct but date is last day of week/month

Comment: @Pratik . . . The question refers to the *last* day.  For the first day, change the `>` to `<`.

Comment: changing > to < also changes the value. I wanted to show first day of week/month instead but I dont want to change the value. It should still show the value of last row

Comment: @BrianDeMilia . . . Of course it didn't work.  I spaced on the join conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this will get you your expected output:

**Last for month:**

```
select t.*
  from tbl t
  join (select max(created_on) as last_for_month
          from tbl
         group by year(created_on), month(created_on)) v
    on t.created_on = v.last_for_month
```

Except where you say you expect:

```
'6','uac','1','2014-07-26 21:53:34'
```

I think what you really want is:

```
'6','uac','2','2014-07-26 21:53:34'
```

(based on the sample data you provided)

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faaa3/4/0

**Last for week:**

```
select t.*
  from tbl t
  join (select max(created_on) as last_for_week
          from tbl
         group by year(created_on), week(created_on)) v
    on t.created_on = v.last_for_week
```

Based on your comment, if you want the last value and the last id for the last of the month, but the value of cnt1 for the first of the month, use the following (change month() to week() if you want the same but for week):

```
select v.id, v2.first_created_on, v.cnt1
  from (select t.id, t.created_on, t.cnt1
          from tbl t
          join (select max(created_on) as last_created_on
                 from tbl
                group by year(created_on), month(created_on)) v
            on t.created_on = v.last_created_on) v
  join (select min(created_on) as first_created_on
          from tbl
         group by year(created_on), month(created_on)) v2
    on year(v.created_on) = year(v2.first_created_on)
   and month(v.created_on) = month(v2.first_created_on)
```

**Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faaa3/5/0

Output:

```
| ID |                 FIRST_CREATED_ON | CNT1 |
|----|----------------------------------|------|
|  4 |    August, 06 2014 21:53:34+0000 |  100 |
|  6 |      July, 06 2014 21:53:34+0000 |    2 |
| 13 | September, 01 2014 21:53:34+0000 |    9 |
```

Comment: This query is giving Syntax error. Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you rename "tbl" to your actual table? It does not have a syntax error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faaa3/4/0

Comment: Ah my bad. Dint realise. Works perfectly. Have another question. Currently it is displaying last day of week/month. Can we show first day of week/month instead but I dont want to change the value. It should still show the value of last row

Comment: @Pratik I believe I've done what you've just described here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faaa3/5/0 . If the output is not what you expect please edit your question with the exact output you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the expected output, one row per year and month. You've specified `created_on` as an expression in the SELECT list, so you are getting the value from the `created_on` column from one row in the each group.

If you want just year and month in the output, you'd need to use a different expression in the SELECT list. For example,

```
DATE_FORMAT(created_on,'%Y-%m') AS yyyy_mm
```

You could use the same expression the GROUP BY clause, rather that two separate expressions.

As another option, you could use the `YEAR(created_on), MONTH(created_on)` in the SELECT list.

---

To get rows "grouped" by week, you could use `WEEK(created_on)` in place of `MONTH(created_on)`.

---

To return the "last" row for each group, the normal pattern is to use an inline view and a JOIN operation.  For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.project
     , t.total_tc
     , t.created_on
  FROM qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail t
  JOIN ( SELECT MAX(r.created_on)
           FROM qa_dashboard.project_qa_coverage_detail r
          GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(r.created_on,'%Y-%m')
       ) s
    ON s.created_on = t.created
```

Note that if there are two (or more) rows with the same `created_on` value, there's a potential for this query to return more than one row for the group.